# Magento - always show free shipping even before postcode/zip entered

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

I have a UK Magento store and I only have one shipping method of free to all customers. My checkout page currently reads

"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time." Until a postcode is entered.

However as I only have one shipping method of free, I always want this method displayed and checked even before the customer has entered a postcode.

Any ideas?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: In the end I cheated a bit and used the translate.csv to override "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time." to "Free shipping".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the standard Magento shipping quote altogether and have a drop down menu so that customers could see all (one) of the shipping options straight away on the basket page. I downloaded and installed this extension and it worked well.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-shipping-method-dropdown-default-shipping-method-on-cart-page

Make sure your default country is United Kingdom in system > config > general

To remove the standard shipping option copy of the following file to your local folder: template/checkout/cart.html and look for the following line:

getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>

Then comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is showing this result. So, you need to remove standard shipping quotes and make a drop down menu so that customers can choose the option according. For this, you need to install the [Magento One Page Checkout Extension](http://magento.ocodewire.com/extensions/one-page-checkout.html) for your online store so that you do not face any kind of difficulty in future.